# Running DotNet Core projects with right click in Windows

Tags: windows, .net-core, registry

I want to run .NET Core projects without opening Visual Studio. These projects have the `csproj` file extension.

Is it possible to run the `dotnet run` command on `csproj` files from the right-click context menu in Windows?

What would I need to add to the registry in order to enable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a right-click context menu item, create a new file and name it `dotnet-run-project.reg`.

Then, copy and paste the following text into your new `dotnet-run-project.reg` file. Finally, run the `dotnet-run-project.reg` file. It'll add a new file association for the `csproj` file.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.csproj\shell\Run Csproj\command]
@="cmd /s /k dotnet run --project \"%1\""
```